# mod_rewrite not working well with trailing slash & css breaks apart

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have just one root directory with index.php in it along with two folder img and css.
I refer to files in this folder like:
src="img/path.png" i.e relative to the root directory.

The other day I had some mod_rewrite question & this is what someone gave me, which seems to wrok fine except for trailing slashes and css/img breaking apart

RewriteRule ^$ index.php?page=1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1&page=1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [L]

This is what is bothering me:

Using Rule1:

www.example.com changes to www.example.com/index.php?page=1 which is great
Also www.example.com/ some how changes to www.example.com which is again great

Using Rule2:

www.example.com/2 changes to www.example.com/index.php?page=2 like what I would want
But using www.example.com/2/ (TRAILING SLASH) also retrieves page=2 but somehow the img and css breaks apart.
I am guessing the problem is with url being treated as directory structure and then it cant find img and css folder there.

Using Rule 3:

www.example.com/Football changes to www.example.com/index.php?category=Football&page=1 again like what I would want
But www.example.com/Football/ (TRAILING SLASH) suffers from the same problem with img and css breaking apart

Using Rule 4:

www.www.example.com/Football/2 even without the trailing slash breaksdown on css and img however the page can retrieve tha page and category correctly.

How do I correct this problem without having to use absolute paths in my html.
Please advise on the trailing slash problem as well.

Comment: ErrorDocument 404 index.php This does not seem to work for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not reference your images/css using relative but starting with a /?

```
/images/blah.jpg
/css/style.css
```

Comment: Yeah that should do it.  /images/blah.jpg would mean look from the root directory, right?

Comment: Yep exactly. It'll load from the host domain

Answer (score 0):

You could add a rule like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|favicon.ico)
# Other rules here
```

The idea is to avoid the rewrite case for an existing file or directory.

Comment: ok so I added

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\.localhost$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


which means trailing slash is no longer a problem. But I didn't get what you are trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

With a trailing slash, the path will be interpreted as a directory. Wherever you include images, css files and such you have to change the paths. Say you have images in an *img* folder, you probably use it in css like:

```
background: url(img/image.png)...
```

Change that to :

```
background: url(/img/image.png) ...
```

Same goes for everywhere you have images referenced or other paths. Using a path that starts with "/" means that you are searching from the root directory. The rules you're using are the rules that I'm ussually using and didn't have any problems with them. Actually, I find it easier to build my paths with a starting "/".

Just as a last example, if you have: *mysite.com/home* and you have `<img src="img/image.png" />` the image will be searched in *mysite.com/img/image.png* which is probably what you want.

But if you have *mysite.com/home/* and `<img src="img/image.png" />` the image must reside in *mysite.com/home/img/image.png* which is not what you want, thus using `<img src="/img/image.png" />` would be the solution for you.